# Xamarin auto-import shortcut

Tags: c#, xamarin, keyboard-shortcuts, monodevelop, auto-import

In eclipse, it's ctrl+shift+o, which automaticly imports everything. But how can I do this in Xamarin? I don't remember every package and there aren't those lightbulbs, which are in Eclipse that would help me to "quick-fix" the problem.

So, is there any shortcut for auto-import everything or just some othere way how to auto-import stuff?

Comment: Xamarin tends to model it's shortcuts after Visual Studio (f7 is build, F5 is debug, F9 insert breakpoint, ctrl-K -> ctrl-K inssert bookmark...)

Comment: Alt ⌥+Return doesn't work

Comment: That's weird. I have a clean install right now.

Comment: Sorry, but the point remains the same. Do I have to write all the using.. lines on my own?

Comment: no dude, use `Ctrl+.`, `alt+Enter` or something.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you select the proper context by moving the cursor to the line of code with the missing `namespace` and then press "Alt ⌥" + "Return ⏎" the refactor/quick fix dialog will show up. If the dialog does not appear validate your keybindings.

[image: Dialog]

[image]

Comment: Sorry what is that Mac keybinding?  I don't know how to read the ⌥ symbol, and its not on my keyboard

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/AppleAlt.jpg it is the "option" or "alt" key http://mac.sillydog.org/archives/pic/option_key.jpg